# Get RCdata Ressiource from file with Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, resources

Hello i want to get or dump rcdata from ressource of file with vb.net
how a can do this and Thank you
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLatv.gif

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any library for doing this directly. Vb.net doesn't like playing with raw data pointers. However there are command line applications that can do this for you.

Have a look at these freeware options:

- [Resource Extract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html)
- [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Then you could just launch the process and parse the outputs.